# Use DataView filtering return syntax error

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I receive data from stored procedure like:

```
       var db = new SQLConnMgr();
       var dtJobs = db.GetTableBySQL(sp);
```

Once I have data I divide it into two datacolumns and insert into two differents datatables like:

```
            DataColumn[] projectsColumns = dtJobs.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => c.ColumnName == "Project Name" || c.ColumnName == "ProjectKey")
    .Select(c => new DataColumn(c.ColumnName, c.DataType))
    .ToArray();

            DataColumn[] designGroupColumns = dtJobs.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
  .Where(c => c.ColumnName == "DesignGroup Name" || c.ColumnName == "DesignGroupId")
  .Select(c => new DataColumn(c.ColumnName, c.DataType))
  .ToArray();

            this.Projects = new DataTable();
            this.Projects.Columns.AddRange(projectsColumns);
            this.DesignGroups = new DataTable();
            this.DesignGroups.Columns.AddRange(designGroupColumns);


            foreach (DataRow row in dtJobs.Rows)
            {
                DataRow aRow = Projects.Rows.Add();
                DataRow bRow = DesignGroups.Rows.Add();
                foreach (DataColumn project in projectsColumns)
                    aRow.SetField(project, row[project.ColumnName]);
                foreach (DataColumn designGroup in designGroupColumns)
                    bRow.SetField(designGroup, row[designGroup.ColumnName]);
            }
```

So now I have two datatables with different data and columns. Now I want to filter Projects `Datatable` in textbox change event. So I do:

```
  private void txtSearchJobName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView dvJobs = this.Projects.DefaultView;
            dvJobs.RowFilter = "Project Name LIKE '%" + txtSearchJobName.Text + "%'";
        }
```

But when I type into textbox it return syntaxt error exception

> System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: 'Syntax error: Missing operand after
>   'Name' operator.'

That happens when I it try to execute   `dvJobs.RowFilter`, I debbug `dvJobs DataView` and it have my Project Name column, I don't know if I doing something wrong in syntaxis. Regards

Comment: Change to _[Project Name] LIKE ...._ The parser is confused by the column name containing a space, so you need to enclose your name between square brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code in the event handler to

```
private void txtSearchJobName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dvJobs = this.Projects.DefaultView;
    dvJobs.RowFilter = "[Project Name] LIKE '%" + txtSearchJobName.Text + "%'";
}
```

The parser is confused by the column name containing a space, so you need to enclose your name between square brackets.

A part from this I would recommend to change your code that creates the two datatables to a more simple

```
 DataTable dtProjects = dtJobs.DefaultView.ToTable(false, 
                               new string[] {"ProjectKey", "Project Name"});
 DataTable dtDesign  = dtJobs.DefaultView.ToTable(false, 
                               new string[] {"DesignGroup Name","DesignGroupId"});
```

This, not only creates the two tables but also copies the data from the original table. See the [DataView.ToTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.totable?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataView_ToTable_System_Boolean_System_String___)

Answer (score 0):

The filter syntax is: "ColumnName Operand Value".

Try: dvJobs.RowFilter = "Name LIKE '%" + txtSearchJobName.Text + "%'";

Examples and more information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8